# MongoDB Node.js driver: callback does not handle exceptions on insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

w3school gives a simple example of inserting an object into a database, but in this example the callback seems not to catch some exceptions and I cannot understand why.

On this modified example,

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
  var myobj;       // undefined
  db.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log('Error: We should see this');
    console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

I am trying to insert an undefined object into a collection and expect the callback to handle the exception by printing out the text ('Error: We should see this').

Instead, the following exception is thrown and the program terminates (as if the whole `connect` expects to be wrapped by try/catch block).

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

Can someone, please, explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running the actual `insertOne` command against the MongoDb server, the `_id` property of the document you are trying to insert is accessed to see if it is currently `0`. You can see this happening in the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/collection.js#L738).

The key point here is that this is **before** the asynchronous processing of the `insertOne` request begins - The error has not occurred during the actual insert process, but rather during a pre-check on the `doc` argument. The code assumes that you have not provided a `null`/`undefined` document, which in this case is not a correct assumption.

Obviously, you can check the document before you pass it in - ensuring that it is not `null`/`undefined` - This would be sensible. Otherwise, you *could* wrap just the `insertOne` call in a `try`/`catch`:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
    var myobj;       // undefined

    try {
        db.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
            if (err) console.log('Error: We should see this');
            console.log("1 document inserted");
            db.close();
        });
    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I'd go with the approach of checking the document is valid before sending it into `insertOne`. You have full control of this and wouldn't need the `try`/`catch`.

In summary, the approach you show is somewhat of a misuse of the driver.